# Java ResultSet.getBigDecimal("COLUMN_NAME").toPlainString() still converts big numbers into exponents

Tags: java, jdbc

When getting a large float (e.g. `4444444444`) from SQL via Java's ResultSet I used :

`ResultSet.getBigDecimal("COLUMN_NAME").toPlainString();` so that It wouldn't get converted to exponent form.

And It really retains the original format, however several digits are lost (`4444440000`), which brings me to assume that internally in `getBigDecimal()`, the float is grabbed in exponent form.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: The type in the database is DECIMAL, not FLOAT I hope?

Answer (score 0):

`toPlainString()` doesn't modify anything in the BigDecimal (which is immutable).

It simply returns its value as a String without using an exponent form.

A BigDecimal is a BigDecimal, just like an int is an int, and doesn't have any specific format. You must choose the format you want each time you transform it to a String.

Comment: It there a possibility that ResultSet's getBigDecimal truncates the data?